# CSS not being respected even though it's linked?

Tags: html, css

Unofortunately, I can't share the exact page because it's a page that you get to AFTER you login (and I can't share login info).  But we have a page that is clearly linked to a CSS page, i.e. if you View Source you see this in the head..

```
 <link href="http://www.insightdirect.com/SelfServStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But the styling from that sheet is not showing up.  In fact, if you inspect any element on the page there is no indication that it's seeing that style sheet AT ALL.

I know it's hard without seeing the page, but is there anything anyone can think of that I should check?

It's clearly linking to a CSS file but appears to be totally ignoring everything in the CSS file.

Comment: Can you at least provide some HTML elements code and the CSS that is supposed to affect those elements?

Comment: Can you click on the element of the css in your code and see if it opens the stylesheet? Might have a misspel in it. Saving your css in the root is not a smart thing to do anyway. If you do that with everything you get a really cluttered area.

Comment: Since you know about element inspector, you might also be aware of the network inspector. Use it to conform that the stylesheet is being downloaded.

Comment: `i.e. if you View Source you see this in the head` That's not always an indication that all is fine. If you're using Chrome, open the developer toolbar and check to see if the browser is having any issues loading that file (check console and network tabs for errors).  Then you can also inspect an element that you know should be having styles applied to it from this linked CSS and browse through what styles are being applied and from where.  It lists what file they're coming from so if you see your stylesheet there but it's being overridden by something, it should tell you.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions everyone.  I was not aware of the Console thing, which let me know what's going on (thanks jmbertucci for the heads up) but again, thank you everyone. The problem..." The page at was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.insightdirect.com/SelfServStyle.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Comment: look at Salmans answer, you haven't removed it yet. also end <style> tag in css

Answer (score 4):

You suffered from the [***blocked mixed content***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content) issue. Use protocol relative URLs to link stylesheets, JavaScript files and images; this minimizes your chances of running into these issues.

```
<link href="//www.insightdirect.com/SelfServStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- notice there is no http/https in the above -->
```

---

[Original answer]: Your stylesheet begins with:

```
<style type="text/css">
```

This is incorrect. Removing this might allow the browser to parse the stylesheet correctly.

Comment: Tried this and the source code shows it just how you wrote it (//www.insightdirect.com/SelfServStyle.css) but it still is blocking it :(  I think I need to find a secure domain

Comment: I see. Since the _admin section_ is hosted on HTTPs, you might as well copy (and link) the CSS file there.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the name of the file and the linux server is case sensitive.

SelfServStyle.css  Vs selfserverstyles.css

```
<link href="http://www.insightdirect.com/SelfServStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://www.insightdirect.com/selfServstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Carefully look the format of the file names. This two file are different in server.